# uncheck radio button by clicking on same

Tags: performance, radio-button

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1" checked="checked" class="radio"/>
        </td>        
        <td>        
          <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="1" checked="checked" class="radio"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to follow default behavior of radio group, but with one more functionality, Suppose any of radio is selected, now if same radio is selected/clicked then it will unchecked itself. I have tried using 'mouseup' event but its not working

```
function radioSearchFn(obj)
{
    if(obj.checked == true)
    {
        obj.checked = false;
        obj.removeAttribute("checked");

    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2te28/152/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120576/how-to-uncheck-checked-radio-button).

Radio buttons are meant to be required, therefore one of them must always be checked. If you want this attribute gone, you need to use checkboxes, which are meant to serve what you need.

[More about checkboxes](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_checkbox)

If you still insist on using radio buttons, try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wuAWn/6/) JQuery code, written in another answer in the post I referred to.

```
var radio_button=false;
$('.radio-button').on("click", function(event){
    var this_input=$(this);
        if(this_input.attr('checked1')=='11')
    {

        this_input.attr('checked1','11')



    }
    else
    {
        this_input.attr('checked1','22')

    }
    $('.radio-button').prop('checked', false);
    if(this_input.attr('checked1')=='11')
    {
        this_input.prop('checked', false);
        this_input.attr('checked1','22')
    }
    else{
        this_input.prop('checked', true);
        this_input.attr('checked1','11')
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I have done with Prototype and its working : http://jsfiddle.net/VBM2Y/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, you could add an attribute instead radio button is checked first time. Later you check this new attribute for next change. Example:

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function () {
         $(this).attr('checked_status', true);
});

$("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('checked_status')) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        $(this).attr('checked_status', false);
    }
});
```