# Drawing with radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a very beginner for Javascript. I tried to draw shapes with some radio buttons. But, the button is not working. When I draw each, it works. What do I need to do here?

```
<h2>Painting Editor</h2>

<br />

<div align="center">
<label>Line <input type="radio" name="Shape" value="Line" id="Line" checked /> </label>
<label>Rectangle <input type="radio" name="Shape" value="Rectangle" id="Rectangle" /> </label>
<label>Circle <input type="radio" name="Shape" value="Circle" id="Circle" /> </label>
```

The part above is to assign the radio buttons.

```
<br />

<div id="sketch">
<canvas id="paint" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    (function () {
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#paint');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
    var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);

    // Pase into integer of Canvas size
    canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
    canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));


    // Creating a tmp canvas
    var tmp_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var tmp_context = tmp_canvas.getContext('2d');
    tmp_canvas.id = 'tmp_canvas';
    tmp_canvas.width = canvas.width;
    tmp_canvas.height = canvas.height;

    sketch.appendChild(tmp_canvas);

    // Mouse Position Setting
    var mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    var last_mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };

    /* Drawing on Paint*/
    tmp_context.lineWidth = 4;
    tmp_context.lineJoin = 'round';
    tmp_context.lineCap = 'round';
    tmp_context.strokeStyle = 'Red';
    tmp_context.fillStyle = 'Red';


    var shape = '';

    document.querySelector('#Line').onchange() = function () {
        if (this.checked)
            shape = 'Line';

        tmp_canvas.style.display = 'block';
    }

    /* Mouse Capturing Work */
    tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        mouse.x = typeof e.offsetX === 'undefined' ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
        mouse.y = typeof e.offsetY === 'undefined' ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;
    });

    tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onLine);

        mouse.x = typeof e.offsetX === 'undefined' ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
        mouse.y = typeof e.offsetY === 'undefined' ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;

        last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
        last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

        onLine();
    });

    tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        tmp_canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onLine);

        // Writing down to real canvas now
        context.drawImage(tmp_canvas, 0, 0);

        // Clearing tmp canvas
        tmp_context.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);
    });

    var onLine = function () {

        // Tmp canvas is always cleared up before drawing.
        tmp_context.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);

        // Line
        tmp_context.beginPath();
        tmp_context.moveTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
        tmp_context.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        tmp_context.stroke();
        tmp_context.closePath();
    };

    document.querySelector('#Rectangle').onchange() = function () {
        if (this.checked)
            shape = 'Rectangle';

        tmp_canvas.style.display = 'block';
    }

    /* Mouse Capturing Work */
    tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        mouse.x = typeof e.offsetX === 'undefined' ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
        mouse.y = typeof e.offsetY === 'undefined' ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;
    });

    tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onRect);

        mouse.x = typeof e.offsetX === 'undefined' ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
        mouse.y = typeof e.offsetY === 'undefined' ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;

        last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
        last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

        onRect();
    });

    tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        tmp_canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onRect);

        // Writing down to real canvas now
        context.drawImage(tmp_canvas, 0, 0);

        // Clearing tmp canvas
        tmp_context.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);
    });

    var onRect = function () {
        // Rectangle
        var x = Math.min(mouse.x, last_mouse.x);
        var y = Math.min(mouse.y, last_mouse.y);
        var width = Math.abs(mouse.x - last_mouse.x);
        var height = Math.abs(mouse.y - last_mouse.y);
        tmp_context.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
    };


    document.querySelector('#Circle').onchange() = function () {
        if (this.checked)
            shape = 'Circle';

        tmp_canvas.style.display = 'block';
    }

    /* Mouse Capturing Work */
    tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        mouse.x = typeof e.offsetX === 'undefined' ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
        mouse.y = typeof e.offsetY === 'undefined' ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;
    });

    tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onCircle);

        mouse.x = typeof e.offsetX === 'undefined' ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
        mouse.y = typeof e.offsetY === 'undefined' ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;

        last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
        last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

        onCircle();
    });

    tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        tmp_canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onCircle);

        // Writing down to real canvas now
        context.drawImage(tmp_canvas, 0, 0);

        // Clearing tmp canvas
        tmp_context.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);
    });

    var onCircle = function () {
        // Circle
        var x = (mouse.x + last_mouse.x) / 2;
        var y = (mouse.y + last_mouse.y) / 2;

        var radius = Math.max(Math.abs(mouse.x - last_mouse.x), Math.abs(mouse.y - last_mouse.y)) / 2;

        var sAngle = 0;
        var eAngle = 2 * Math.PI;

        tmp_context.beginPath();
        tmp_context.arc(x, y, radius, sAngle, eAngle);
        tmp_context.stroke();
        tmp_context.closePath();
    };
}());
</script>
```

Created temp canvas and I drew each circle, rectangle, and line. If I make it separately, then it works as I said. I want to combine them with radio buttons, but it didn't work.

Ex. If I click a line radio button, then only line is drawn. etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have extra parenthesis after `onchange` on these lines

```
document.querySelector('#Line').onchange() = function () {

document.querySelector('#Rectangle').onchange() = function () {

document.querySelector('#Circle').onchange() = function () {
```

It should be

```
document.querySelector('#Line').onchange = function () {
```

This test seems to work a lot better without the parenthesis: http://jsfiddle.net/rrb1xxjs/

---

You can have a single set of function bound on `mouseup` and `mousedown`, calling a function that check the value of `shape` and call the requested drawing function:

```
function draw() {
    // Tmp canvas is always cleared up before drawing.
    tmp_context.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);

    switch(shape) {
        case 'Line': onLine(); break;
        case 'Rectangle': onRect(); break;
        case 'Circle': onCircle(); break;
    }
}
```

Also, since the Line radio button is selected by default, the `shape` variable should be initialized accordingly

```
var shape = 'Line';
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/djd5m4yu/1/)

That may not be the overall best way to do this, but I think it's what best matches your existing code.

Comment: I want to try working by radio button actions, but either switch or if statement doesn't seem to work correctly.

document.querySelector('#Line').onchange() = function() {}

is to make it separate regarding on the radio button action as I understood.

Comment: I updated with an example of what it should be. ```onchange() = function() {``` is not valid javascript.

Comment: Even onchange() is changed to onchange, button is not recognizing. 

document.querySelector('#Line').onchange = function () {
- This is function call, so I cannot use if statement here.

I tried to use switch, but it was not working as well.

Are there any ways to configure which button is on action?

switch(shape)
{
case "Line":
.....
case "Rect":
....

Something like this..

Comment: Updated with the answer of this other problem, using switch as you suggested

Comment: Radio button shouldn't be empty to declare something what you'are saying?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Have you checked the example: http://jsfiddle.net/djd5m4yu/1/ ?

Comment: Yes, I checked. I mean that I cannot place empty when I use a radio button? And, what's the difference between using script without function() call and with function() call? You removed function() call very top.

Comment: I'm still not sure to understand "place empty". About unchecked radio buttons, you can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120576/how-to-uncheck-checked-radio-button)

Comment: I removed the "function()" at the first line because it is not required in jsfiddle (the tool used for the examples). That's a very specific situation, _you should keep it for you code_. It allows to avoid conflicts between the variable of your code and variables from other libraries.