# Deselect a radio option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [bootstrap radio buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) and would like to allow deselection of a radio group. This can be done using an extra button [(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/94ae9j0e/). Instead of an extra button, however, I would like to deselect a selected radio option if the option is clicked when it's active.

I have tried this

```
$(".btn-group label").on("click", function(e) { 

    var clickedLabel = $(this);

        if ($(clickedLabel).hasClass("active"))
        {
            // an active option was clicked => deselect it
            $(clickedLabel).children("input:radio").prop("checked", false)
            $(clickedLabel).removeClass("active");
        }
    }
)
```

but there seems to be a race condition: the event of clicking the label that I use seems to be used by bootstrap.js to set the clicked label option to "active". If I introduce a timeout, the class "active" is removed successfully:

```
$(".btn-group label").on("click", function(e) { 

    var clickedLabel = $(this);

        if ($(clickedLabel).hasClass("active"))
        {
            setTimeout(function() {
                // an active option was clicked => deselect it
                $(clickedLabel).children("input:radio").prop("checked", false)
                $(clickedLabel).removeClass("active");
            }, 500)
        }
    }
)
```

How can I toggle a selected option successfully without using a timeout?? Thank you for help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120576/how-to-uncheck-checked-radio-button

Comment: Chris, this works for regular radio buttons, not for the bootstrap buttons (they have a label around the input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Instead of using two method's preventDefault & stopPropagation, use return false, will work same.
>
> The difference is that return false; takes things a bit further in
>   that it also prevents that event from propagating (or "bubbling up")
>   the DOM. The you-may-not-know-this bit is that whenever an event
>   happens on an element, that event is triggered on every single parent
>   element as well.

```
$(".btn-group label").on("click", function(e) { 

    var clickedLabel = $(this);



          if ($(clickedLabel).hasClass("active"))
            {
                // an active option was clicked => deselect it
                $(clickedLabel).children("input:radio").prop("checked", false)
                $(clickedLabel).removeClass("active");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This solution is much better than mine.  Using return completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 2):

After messing with your code in jsfiddle for a while I figured out that a combination of preventDefault() and stopPropagation() does the trick.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/temd8tt9/)

and the code:

```
$(".btn-group label").on("click", function(e) { 

    var clickedLabel = $(this);

        if ($(clickedLabel).hasClass("active"))
        {
            // an active option was clicked => deselect it
            $(clickedLabel).children("input:radio").prop("checked", false)
            $(clickedLabel).removeClass("active");
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: preventDefault & stopPropagation - great, thanks ;o)

Comment: @peter Thanks glad I could help! However Jhon Carpenter has a better solution than mine that i think should be accepted instead.