# how can stop function multi fire when two div clicked at same time in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, click

I want call my function when clickme or clickme2 div is clicked , also i want call my function just one time,but it will called 2 times, how can stop mlti call when two div is clicked at sametime? thank you

HTML

```
<div id="clickme">
   <div id="clickme2">Add</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{margin:0 auto; padding:0;}

#clickme {
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:#999;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:150px;
    font-size:35px;
}   
#clickme2 {
    height:120px;
    width:120px;
    border:dashed thin #003;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#clickme, #clickme2").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(this).css("color", "#CCC");       
})
$("#clickme, #clickme2").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#000");       
})

$("#clickme, #clickme2").click(function() {
    click_event() 
})

var i = 1;
function click_event() {
    alert(i)
    i++;    
}
```

Comment: add a class to the parent div and access it. No need to provide separate ids to both the div.

Comment: please more explain @sagar patro , or if you think it is my answer please write it in answer section , thank you

Comment: @MojtabaSh Use the parent div alone to fire those event handlers.

Comment: I need two div at same time, i wrote a simple code here, i have many many same events in my codes that i shoud fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your div `clickme2` lies within `clickme`. Therefore any click on `clickme2` will also be a click on `clickme`. Because of this, any click handler you assign to `clickme` will be triggered by a click on `clickme2`. What I would do is assign the click handler only to `clickme2` and then the handler will only be triggered once.

If there is some reason you really need to place the same handler on `clickme` as `clickme2` then you are going to have to create something like a rudimentary ***mutex*** ([mutual excluder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)).

This will be fairly easy to do, even in a scripting language. Basically write something like this.

```
var mutex = false;

function calledTwice() {
    if (!mutex) {
        mutex = true; // similar to locking a mutex
        // your code goes here
    } else {
        // this function was already called - second handler resets the mutex
        mutex = false;
    }
}
```

This should ensure (or, because it's imperfect in a scripting language, make it very likely) that this event handler is only really triggered once.

### Edit

**For More than two Superimposed Divs**

You will have to accompany the mutex boolean with a number that counts down. You would do something like this

```
var mutex = false;
var count = n; // n is the number of calls you expect

function calledTwice() {
    if (!mutex) {
        mutex = true; // similar to locking a mutex
        // your code goes here
    } else {
        // this function was already called, but only reset if all calls are passed
        count--; // decrement the count
        if (count <= 0) {
            // now this is the last call - you may reset the mutex
            count = n; // make sure to do this before resetting the boolean
            mutex = false;         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @William Rosenbloom , it doing work but like this: if (!mutex) {
    mutex = true;
   } else {
    click_event() ;mutex = false; 
   }

Comment: it working for twice called but i tried to reach one call when 3 or more div is clicked at same time right now

Comment: well i think it can't stop click event for 3 or more time , if you know any way for stop that please say me, absloutly i will accpect your answer, thank you

Comment: excellent, thank you @William Rosenbloom, it will stop them, thanks again

Comment: Haha no problem it was fun.

Comment: so for n numbers can assign same title to divs and get $('[tiltle="clickme"]').length to count variable

Comment: Well you can't actually assign the same title (I assume you mean id) because that's against the rules of HTML. However you can attach a method like this to multiple simultaneous triggers (like superimposed divs), and the method will only execute once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a line: event.stopPropagation();

```
$("#clickme, #clickme2").click(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    click_event() 
})
```

Here you can see your updated fiddle, which is working fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/Leu7vmf6/1/

Comment: thank you, but it don't show any alert, i need show that for one time

Comment: please pass the event inside the callback method.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33896210/2862142

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's an issue with Mozilla we have to pass event in argument.

```js
$("#clickme, #clickme2").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(this).css("color", "#CCC");       
})
$("#clickme, #clickme2").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#000");       
})

$("#clickme, #clickme2").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    click_event() 
})

var i = 1;
function click_event() {
    alert(i)
    i++;    
}
```

```css
*{margin:0 auto; padding:0;}

#clickme {
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:#999;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:150px;
    font-size:35px;
}   
#clickme2 {
    height:120px;
    width:120px;
    border:dashed thin #003;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickme">
   <div id="clickme2">Add</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not a issue, you have to catch that event then you can handle that, otherwise how will you know on which you are Propagating event.

Comment: Thanks @John, for sharing this link.