# Checkbox and Radio buttons behaviour

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am using a set of checkboxes to have some drop-down menus by switching their `display:none;` to `display:block` when box or radio is checked.

This is the checkbox version : https://jsfiddle.net/hw207q2L/

and this is the radio version : https://jsfiddle.net/3xzuw47x/

I'd like to combine both so that when opening a new part it closes the other ones (radio behaviour) ; while at the same time being able to close the part I opened by clicking it again (checkbox behaviour).

Any ideas that wouldn't involve javascript ? I'd like to restrain from using js, but if it's not possible tell me.

Comment: Not possible with just CSS

Comment: @DaniP Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires functionality that prevents default behavior, so it's unlikely to make it happen without the using of additional framework or javascript.

This not exactly a duplicate, but please check [How to uncheck checked radio button [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120576/how-to-uncheck-checked-radio-button).

Just use this javascript in your second version of code:

```
var allRadios = document.getElementsByName('titles');
var booRadio;
var x = 0;
for(x = 0; x < allRadios.length; x++){
    allRadios[x].onclick = function() {
        if(booRadio == this){
            this.checked = false;
            booRadio = null;
        }else{
            booRadio = this;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: If you found an answer you can post the link as a comment or mark as duplicate but repost the answer here just copy / paste ...

Comment: Copied it and works like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: How do I do duplicate?